# entity framework 5 selecting dynamic colums

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Is there a way to select specific column in entity framework at run-time.
For example i have an Entity **User** with properties **Title,FirstName,LastName,Email** and i want to specify specific column(s) to select at run-time

```
Using u as New UserEntities
 dim user = (From usr in u.Users
             Select usr.<<Relpacing this property with the selected property>>).ToList
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is really best for COMPILE time queries. It isn't as easy to use when you need dynamic structures. In that case, you may want to look into Entity SQL and the Query Builder methods. One of the best ways of getting started with this is to check out the samples in the EF Query Samples project at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFQuerySamples.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have an entity 'Users' in your data context.  Let's assume that your User entity has a firstName property (or column on the data table behind it if you like).  So to retrieve the first names from your User entity you would need a linq  query running along these lines:

```
Using u as new UserEnties
     Dim query = (From n in u.Users
     select n.firstName).ToList()
     'now do something with your list
 End Using
```

Linq is not the easiest of things to get your head around at first, and mines a bit rusty to say the least.  There are however some good basic examples on MSDN to get you started off in the right direction.  Hopefully this will at least get you pointed in the right direction.